# How do borders affect size of inner divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how borders affect the size and visualisation of an inner div. I have this problem in my application, where a border is displayed around fields with errors, and I can't seem to get the CSS right. (BTW, it's obvious that I don't quite "get" CSS just yet. I am working on it).

Consider this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Booking Dojo Application</title>

    <style type="text/css">

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#appContainer {
  height: 50px;

  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

#innerContainer {
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

#ruler {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;

}

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="ruler"></div>

    <div id="appContainer">
      <div id="innerContainer">
        <span>AHAH</span>
      </div>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

If I don't specify the width of the inner div, then its width is the same as the parent *including* the border.

But then, if I DO specify the inner div's width, something weird happen: Chrome puts the border "out", but... only to the right?!?

I am obviously missing something. So:

- Why am I seeing what I am seeing?
- What I would love to do, is know what the inner div's width should be specified as in order to get the same result as "without width"? (Other than going "99%" which seems to "work" in my app, but.... meh )

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/X3gw6/1/

You need:

```
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

More info:
http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Basically, inner div height and width are bigger, because of borders... that caused problems...

Answer (score 0):

It's because borders add to the elements height and width. So a width of 100% is 500px plus 5px left and 5px right border = 510px. You can see that `width: 490px;` makes the inner container inline with the other elements: http://jsfiddle.net/2wLQR/

`box-sizing: border-box;` will stop it from going out of line: http://jsfiddle.net/2wLQR/1/

Answer (score 0):

By default border is added to the width. If you do not specify a width the default is to take all of the space it can and make it fit. So the inner width is 100%-borders.

When you specify a width you are by default specifying the inner width. 100% plus borders > 100%.

box-sizing:border-box; rule when added means you are specifying the width with borders. This is part of CSS3.

If widths are percentages but you need a fixed size border, box-sizing:border-box; rule makes it possible. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp